# How to implement AddToRoleAsync in the user store

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using the following user store:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<AspNetUsers>, IUserPasswordStore<AspNetUsers>, IUserSecurityStampStore<AspNetUsers>, ILookupNormalizer, IUserClaimStore<AspNetUsers>, IUserRoleStore<AspNetUsers>
```

How do I implement the implementation for AddToRoleAsync?

I have no idea what I'm doing, this is the mess I have so far:

```
public async Task AddToRoleAsync(AspNetUsers user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var role = await roleStore.FindByNameAsync(Normalize(roleName), cancellationToken);
        if(role != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(role.Name))
        {
            user.AspNetUserRoles.Add(new AspNetUserRoles()
            {
                RoleId = role.Id,
                Role = new AspNetRoles()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Name = role.Name,
                    NormalizedName = role.NormalizedName
                },
                User = user,
                UserId = user.Id
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Role doesn't exist, please create it");
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

### Update

I think this is all I need but a confirmation would be great.

```
user.AspNetUserRoles.Add(new AspNetUserRoles()
{
    RoleId = role.Id
});
```

Comment: Don’t you want to persist to database?

Comment: @Nikolaus yes, but I'm using the CreateAsync method in the UserStore for that.  So first I add the roles to the user, then I call CreateAsync to create the user or UpdateAsync to update the user.

Comment: Usually, the second version should be enough.